# prependTo closest specified Parent div from an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use JQuery from inside an `iframe` to `.prependTo` a `.class` `div` inside the Parent.

This has multiples of the same .class. **EDIT And iframes

Everything is on the same domain.

**So, from inside the Main document:**

```
<div class="NewPHOTOS">
    **<!--PUT ME HERE!-->**
    <div class="LinePhoto">
        <a href="images/518279f07efd5.gif" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/thumb_518279f07efd5.gif" width="50" height="50">
        </a>
    </div>

   <iframe class="uploadLineID_55" width="800px" height="25px" src="../../uploads/uploadiframe.php" scrolling="no" seamless></iframe>
</div>
```

**Script inside the iframe**:

```
$(document).on("click", '#TEST', function() {

  appendImagetoParent();

});


function appendImagetoParent()  {

var data = '<div class="LinePhoto"><a href="images/TEST.gif" target="_blank"><img src="images/thumb_TEST.gif" width="50" height="50"></a></div>';

$(".NewPHOTOS", window.parent.document).each(function() { $(data).prependTo($(".NewPHOTOS"));
});

/* $(data).prependTo( $(".NewPHOTOS", window.parent.document) ); This prepends to Every .NewPHOTOS */}
```

I've been running around in circles and googleing for hours now. I can't figure this out.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**
I used, works great!

```
 $(parent.document).find('.' + frameElement.className )
                      .closest('.NewPHOTOS')
                      .prepend( data );
```

Comment: Is there more than one iframe inside a div with class newphotos on the page?

Comment: It might be better to attach a listener in the parent page for the load event of each iframe, this way you can target the frame and workout its parents('.NewPHOTOS')

Comment: Yes. Both have multiples.

Comment: If the commented line prepends to all the elements with that class, what do you expect? To prepend to just the first, the last, one somewhere in the middle, every other ?

Comment: I am assuming to the parent of the iframe

Comment: What is the content-type being returned by `../../uploads/uploadiframe.php`? Is the script in that enclosed in a `<script>` block or is the content-type set to `application/javascript`?

Comment: I put that there as an example. I'm looking to prependTo the div the iframe is in in the parent

Comment: Wrapped in <script> tags.

Comment: Do all the iFrames have different classes ?

Comment: All the iframes have a different class name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", '#TEST', appendImagetoParent);

function appendImagetoParent()  {

    var div = $('<div />', {'class':'linePhoto'}),
        a   = $('<a />',   {href:'images/TEST.gif', target:'_blank'}),
        img = $('<img />', {src:'images/thumb_TEST.gif', width:'50', height:'50'});

    $(parent.document).find('.' + frameElement.className )
                      .closest('.NewPHOTOS')
                      .prepend( div.append( a.append(img) ) );
}
```

Get the class of the containing iFrame with `frameElement.className`, and use that class to find the right iFrame in the parent document, then find the closest `.NewPHOTOS` element, and prepend the content, created in a more jQuery'ish way.

Comment: @Monty - thats excellent, as I was'nt 100% sure it would, and I had no real way of testing it !